# How to make my Style Effect all ScrollViewers but one of them

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a Style for ScrollViewer that will changes look of every scrollbar in my  app :

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">  
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Silver"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter 
                                x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"/>                           
                            <ScrollBar

                            Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                            <ScrollBar 

                            Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>



            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 

                Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" 

                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"

                Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"

                Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility"

                Value="Auto"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

        <!--Scrollbar Thumbs-->
        <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                            <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Background="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollBar}}}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="7" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--ScrollBars-->
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}},Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"  />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"  />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="8" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                                </Track.Thumb>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>





                            <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                                <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                                <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="8" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
    </Style>
```

So is it OK to have styles like this to effect every control or I have to set a name for this style and use it.

I have a Costume Control that contain a Listbox and i want all of my containers be effected by  ScrollViewer style but this one. how can i do this ?

This is a part of my control That contain a listBox. It is a Hamburger Menu :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HamburgerMenu">
    <Style TargetType="local:HamburgerMenu">
        <Style.Resources>

            <!-- Fill Brushes -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" Color="#40000000" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" Color="#80FFFFFF" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" Color="Transparent" />            
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:HamburgerMenu">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <ResourceDictionary>
                            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                                <ResourceDictionary Source="/HamburgerMenu;component/Themes/ListBoxStyle.xaml"/>
                                <ResourceDictionary Source="/HamburgerMenu;component/Themes/ToggleButtonStyle.xaml"/>
                            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                            <Style TargetType="local:HamburgerMenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=MenuItemForeground}"/>
                                <Setter Property="SelectionIndicatorColor" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=SelectionIndicatorColor}"/>
                                <Setter Property="MouseOverColor" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=MouseOverColor}"/>
                                <Setter Property="PressedColor" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=PressedColor}"/>
                                <Setter Property="PressedBorderColor" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=PressedBorderColor}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Data" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=Data}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ResourceDictionary>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="50" >
                            <ToggleButton ToolTip="{TemplateBinding HamburIconTooltipMinimizeMessage}" x:Name="menuIcon" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="50" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=IsOpen}"> <!-- hi -->
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Path Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="path"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="Uniform" Width="30" Fill="{TemplateBinding MenuIconColor}"
                                      Data="M424,135H89c-4.418,0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8,8-8h335c4.418,0,8,3.582,8,8S428.418,135,424,135z">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform x:Name="MyAnimatedScaleTransform1"  CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="0" />
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                    <Path Margin="0,9,0,9" x:Name="path1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="Uniform" Width="30" Fill="{TemplateBinding MenuIconColor}" 
                                      Data="M424,135H89c-4.418,0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8,8-8h335c4.418,0,8,3.582,8,8S428.418,135,424,135z">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <MatrixTransform x:Name="myMatrixTransform" >
                                                <MatrixTransform.Matrix >                                                    
                                                    <Matrix  OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" M11="1" M12="0" />
                                                </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                                            </MatrixTransform>
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                    <Path Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="path2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="top" Stretch="Uniform" Width="30" Fill="{TemplateBinding MenuIconColor}" 
                                      Data="M424,135H89c-4.418,0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8,8-8h335c4.418,0,8,3.582,8,8S428.418,135,424,135z">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform x:Name="MyAnimatedScaleTransform"  CenterX="1" CenterY="1" Angle="0" />
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                </StackPanel>                              
                        </ToggleButton>
                        </Border>

                        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" Style="{StaticResource listboxStyle}" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers >
                        <Trigger Property="IsOpen" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="menuIcon" Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=HamburIconTooltipMaximizeMessage}"/>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <!-- hide HamburgerIcon *************************************************************************************************************************************  -->
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <MatrixAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="myMatrixTransform" 
                                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix" DoesRotateWithTangent="True" 
                                                                          Duration="0:0:0.3" BeginTime="0:0:0.3" >
                                                    <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M -35 0 C 0 0, 0 0, 5 0"/>
                                                    </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                                </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
                                                <MatrixAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="myMatrixTransform" 
                                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix" DoesRotateWithTangent="False" 
                                                                          Duration="0:0:0.5" BeginTime="0:0:0.6" >
                                                    <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 5 0 C 0 0, 0 0, 0 0"/>
                                                    </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                                </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
                                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="path1"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                    To="1"  BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="00:00:00" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.8"/>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.9">                                                   
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-55" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-45" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="10" KeyTime="0:0:0.7" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.9" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)" Duration="0:0:0.9">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="55" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="45" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-10" KeyTime="0:0:0.7" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.9" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- Show HamburgerIcon *************************************************************************************************************************************  -->
                                        <MatrixAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="myMatrixTransform" 
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix" DoesRotateWithTangent="False" 
                                                                  Duration="0:0:0.5" BeginTime="0:0:0.1" >
                                            <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M 0 0 C 0 0, 0 0, -35 0"/>
                                            </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                        </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="path1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="0"  Duration="00:00:0.1" AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.8"  BeginTime="00:00:0.5"  />
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.8" >
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="10" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-45" KeyTime="0:0:0.4" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-55" KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-45" KeyTime="0:0:0.6" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform1"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"

                                            Duration="0:0:0.8" >
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-10" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="45" KeyTime="0:0:0.4" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="55" KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="45" KeyTime="0:0:0.6" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>



                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>




                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="menuIcon" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter  TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=MouseOverColor}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="menuIcon" Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=PressedColor}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=PressedBorderColor}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="IsOpen" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>

                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                         To="330"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.3" AccelerationRatio="0.1" DecelerationRatio="0.9"/>



                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                         To="300"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.2" BeginTime="0:0:0.3" AccelerationRatio="0.1" DecelerationRatio="0.9"/>

                            </Storyboard>

                        </Storyboard>



                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                         To="50"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.3" AccelerationRatio="0.1" DecelerationRatio="0.9"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I think create a costume ControlTemplate for every container is hard to do if i can just change this one! 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Before you define your new default style, define one with a key. If it appears before the new default style, it won't inherit from the new default style.

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lavender" />
</Style>
```

...

```
<!-- The first one will be lavender. The second won't. -->
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ScrollViewer Height="20" />
    <ScrollViewer Height="20" Style="{StaticResource DefaultScrollViewerStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you base (using **BasedON**) your style for a particular instance on the type, it overrides the global style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollViewer}}">

<Setter Property="Tag" Value="Silver"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>

__YOUR_OTHER_KEYS__

</Style>
```

Comment: I think you'd have to then set style to {x:Null} on the one you don't want the new default style on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both.

I Put this Style in my Costume Control resources and use it for my ListBox base on your Answers And it works fine :

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="listboxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=ScrollBarVisibility}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="0" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>



 <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" Style="{StaticResource listboxStyle}" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Comment: cant stress this more... new users need to know that when someone has invested their time and effort the least they can do is to acknowledge that!